# How to calculate market share in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data set for 10 countries. Each country has more than 8 products and my company has 3 products A,B,C which are sold in each of the country.

So Now, I want to calculate the market share for my products country wise.

for E.g. If total sale for 8 products in country 1 is 100 and sale for products A+B+C is 35, then market share of my company in country1 is 35/100= 35%
.

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you want to do with that afterwards, if you are just interested in the number, do the following:

1. Create a calculated field `TotalSalesPerCountry` with `{fixed [country]: sum([Sales])}` (calculates the total sales per country)
2. Create a calculated field `CompanySalesPerCountry` with `{fixed [country]: sum(IIF([Product] = 'A' OR [Product] = 'B' OR [Product] = 'C',[Sales],0))}` (calculates the total sum per country where `[PRODUCT]` = A, B or C)
3. Create a calculated field `MarketShare` with `AVG([CompanySalesPerCountry]) / AVG([TotalSalesPerCountry])`
4. Change the Properties for the last field to 'Percent', drag `[Country]` to rows and `[MarketShare]` to columns